# HTML Table colspan with Odd Number of Rows

Tags: html

I am aiming to create a table like this using a simple table with colspan:
[image: Table with 3 Rows Using Colspan]

I used this code to try to replicate it:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td colspan="2">7</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The following is the output. Cell 7 is not sized correctly. 
[image: Colspan Weird Behavior]

The table is supposed to have 4 columns. And each row, when respecting the cells with colspan, totals to 4. How can this be done without introducing a row with 4 cells?

Comment: Does it have to be a table? this would be a lot simpler with grid https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp Otherwise I think your only option would be to add a row with 4 empty columns and set the `tr` like this: `<tr style="visibility: hidden;">`

Comment: It doesn't have too. I was just curious why it behaves like that.

Comment: Your table contains 4 columns, it just happens that width of second column is very small because there is no text in it. You can test it by adding another row like `<tr> <td>9</td> <td>10</td> <td>11</td> <td>12</td> </tr>`. Anyway your problem can be simplified to example containing only cells 3,4 and 6,7 OR 1,3,4 (first column will also be very smal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using a table:

HTML:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">1</td>
            <td colspan="1">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">3</td>
            <td colspan="1">4</td>
            <td colspan="1">5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1">6</td>
            <td colspan="2">7</td>
            <td colspan="1">8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="visibility: hidden;">
            <td colspan="1"></td>
            <td colspan="1"></td>
            <td colspan="1"></td>
            <td colspan="1"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

CSS:

```
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
 }
td { 
    padding: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

---

### Using [CSS grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp):

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="one">1</div>
    <div class="two">2</div>
    <div class="three">3</div>
    <div class="four">4</div>
    <div class="five">5</div>
    <div class="six">6</div>
    <div class="seven">7</div>
    <div class="eight">8</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
        'one one one two'
        'three three four five'
        'six seven seven eight';
        width: 50%;
        grid-gap: 2px;
        padding: 2px;
        background: black;
}

.grid-container div{
    padding: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
}

.one { grid-area: one; }
.two { grid-area: two; }
.three { grid-area: three; }
.four { grid-area: four; }
.five { grid-area: five; }
.six { grid-area: six; }
.seven { grid-area: seven; }
.eight{ grid-area: eight; }
```

Comment: So I guess the browser needs a reference row with the greatest number of cells to properly size the cells with colspans.

Comment: @RandalCunanan yeah, my guess is it automatically sets the number of columns to the max number in any given row and ignores it if you tell it to go over that number, but I would have to mess around with it for a while to be sure